# I want to print a 1-dimensional array using a for loop neatly. (java)

Tags: java, arrays, printf

I am trying to print a 1-dimensional array in a clearly labeled output presentation. I have a method that takes no arguments to print the one-dimensional array, and so far I've created a for loop that prints the contents of the array from id[0] to id[n-1]. The main task I want to accomplish is in my main method I call the method that displays an array 3 times. The output needs to clearly define the results for each call. Ex: Results for part A : (43,45,43,4,5,). Should I use printf or how should I approach the problem. Tried looking on this site for a while, but couldn't find anything specific enough to help.

So far I have

```
public void displaySubsets(){

   for(int i : array) {
   System.out.print("(");
   System.out.print(array[i]);
   System.out.print(")");
```

}

Comment: Some comments: the code snippet is broken - a closing bracket `}` is missing,  Also, in the `foreach` loop an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown in the code `array[i]` because here `i` is not an index but the element of array.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do the following:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

or if you want to roll your own. (assumes the array is not empty or null).

```
System.out.print("(" + array[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
   System.out.print(", " + array[i]);
}
System.out.println(")");
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is one way of doing it:

Iterate over the array an concatenating the numbers into a new string variable.

```java
  static void printArray(){
    String printFormat = "";
    System.out.println("Array Length: " + array.length);\
    //iterate over the array
    for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (i+1 == array.length){
        //If is the last value in the array we don't want to add the ", "
        //concatenate the array's value into a new string without ", "
        printFormat = printFormat + array[i];
      }else{
        //concatenate the arrays value into a new string
        printFormat = printFormat + array[i] +", ";
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Results for part A : (" + printFormat + ")");
  }
```

Click [here to run the code](https://jdoodle.com/ia/B4)

Answer (score 0):

### There's more than 1 way to do it:

I would opt for our friend "Java 8 Streams", more specifically the stream() method of Arrays class. It makes it elegant, intuitive and efficient.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 43, 45, 43, 4, 5 }; 
        System.out.print("(");
        Arrays.stream(arr)
              .forEach( e -> System.out.print(e + ",") );
        System.out.println(")");
    }
}
```

> Output: (43,45,43,4,5,)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can solve this.

**Alternative 1**

One way you can do this is just do:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Like other mentioned.

**Alternative 2**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Main main = new Main();
   int array[] = {43,45,43,4,5};
   System.out.println(main.printArray(array));
 }

public String printArray(int[] array){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("(");
    
    for(int i : array){
        builder.append(i);
        builder.append(", ");
    }
    
    builder.append(")");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

I like to use StringBuilder when it comes to printing because it's faster than just doing System.out.println().

Hope it was useful!